# CSS rules contained in a class doesn't apply to a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, rules

I've been all over the internet in order to find a answer for this problem Im having.
I have a div which is supposed to be the header of my page - it will host other divs with links within.
This div should have a "master" positioning within which the inner "link divs" should take place.

When I first created the page, this div was up and working with the use of "position:fixed" and "transform:translate(-50%, -50%)" as I've seen somewhere in StackOverflow and started loving.
After I added a "container" tag and some JqueryUI code to make it work fancily, it stopped working - It Seems That it's not recognizing the class, not even the borders are being placed.

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></SCRIPT>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></SCRIPT>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar" id="navprinc">
            <div class="navbutton" id="btnini">Main</div>
            <div class="navbutton" id="btnsobre">About</div>
            <div class="navbutton" id="btnconv">Invitation</div>
            <div class="navbutton" id="btnlista">List</div>
            <div class="navbutton" id="btnfoto">Pics</div>
            <div class="navbutton" id="btncont">Contact</div>
        </div>
        <div class="contentReceiver">
            <iframe src="" frameborder="0">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Now the Css that Matters:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ffbdc7; 

}
div.navbar{
    position:fixed;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    width: 65%;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #ffc4cd;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 3px black solid;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.navbutton{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 110px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    width: 170px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;


    background-color: #cc919a;
}

.contentReceiver{
    position: fixed;
    top: 54%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    width: 63%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #ffc4cd;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 3px black solid;
    border-top: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;    
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And then some of the Script just to know what's happening:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Hidings
    $('#navprinc').hide();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {        
            $('#navprinc').toggle( "blind", {direction:'left'}, 2500);
        }, 500);
    });

});
```

If not important, please dont mid the extra unused Id's and the iframe - I'll add content there later.

Thanks for your willingness to help!

EDIT1: It works fine on fiddle, but the class is not being applied outside of it! I've changed the script in order to try and make it more look alike what I have. I Think there's something overriding the class, is the only answer! But still I cant find where!

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle showing the issue?

Comment: What's this supposed to be doing `$('principal.html').ready(function(){`?

Comment: @j08691 Its supposed to make a blind effect when the page loads principal.html is the page that the code is included.

Answer (score 0):

For the transform to work you have to tell the fixed div where to be first.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5LTsP/)

*Probable* revised **CSS**

```
div.navbar{
    position:fixed;
    top:0; /* be at the top */
    left:50%; /* put top left of div at 50% over */

    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%); /* bring it back 505 of it's own width */
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);

    width: 65%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #ffc4cd;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 3px black solid;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: In Fiddle it works almost perfect - you reminded me of the top and left that I took out because of noobness (I've been a long time without touching the code so I forgot what was its use). But it still doesnt work in my code maybe the Script interferes in it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it:
Somehow "Navbar" is not a class name that can be defined for me (I dont know why, this happens from time to time).
I just solved making a new class, keeping that one "alive", copying it and assigning the div the other class.
Btw: Using chrome inspect element is realy cool in figuring this kind of troubles.